# Problema al obtener valor de ng-model con Onsen Dialog

Tags: html, angularjs, alertdialog

Buen día, desde hace tiempo he tenido un problema con Onsen UI, específicamente el componente Dialog.

Parece ser un problema de alcance del Scope o del Controller. Por ejemplo:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

$scope.showEditDialog = function($event, tag) {
 $scope.tagEdit = tag;

 ons.createPopover('editAgenda.html', {
    parentScope: $scope
    }).then(function(alertDialog) {

    $scope.editAgendaDialog = alertDialog;
    $scope.editAgendaDialog.show($event.target);

   });

  };

$scope.simpleAgendaEdition = function(value) {

    $scope.newValue=value;
    $scope.updateOnServer($scope.tagEdit, $scope.newValue, $scope.id);
    $scope.hideEditDialog();
}
});



<body ng-controller="MainController">

<ons-template id="editAgenda.html" >
    <ons-popover direction="up down"  cancelable>
        <div class="alert-dialog-title w3-padding-4">
            Edit Title
        </div>
        <div class="alert-dialog-content">
            <textarea ng-show="tagEdit=='titulo'" ng-model="newValue" placeholder="Title"></textarea>
        </div

       <div class="alert-dialog-footer">

         <button ng-click="simpleAgendaEdition(newDate)" class="alert-dialog-button">OK</button>

       </div>>
    </ons-popover>
</ons-template>
```

Al crear el dialog puedo evaluar correctamente el valor de $scope.tagEdit, sin embargo, no puedo obtener el valor de $scope.newValue en el MainController, este se queda vacío "" como si no hubiese cambiado en el dialog. Lo extraño es que si yo agrego esta linea:

```
{{newValue}}
```

dentro del dialog, puedo ver claramente que el ng-model si cambia, pero no es posible usar ese valor en el MainController, para solucionar temporalmente esto,  envío el valor del ng-model directamente en la función, como un parametro

```
   <button ng-click="simpleAgendaEdition(newDate)" class="alert-dialog-button">OK</button>
```

Pero pienso que es una mala forma de hacerlo, cual sería la mejor forma de obtener el valor del ng-model? hay alguna configuración que esté omitiendo?
Me parece curioso que puedo acceder a las funciones del MainController e incluso a las variables que ya existen, pero no puedo obtener el valor modificado en el onsen dialog.

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Al crear el dialog puedo evaluar correctamente el valor de $scope.tagEdit, sin embargo, no puedo obtener el valor de $scope.newValue en el MainController, este se queda vacío "" como si no hubiese cambiado en el dialog.

Esto sucede por que el dialog crea su propio `$scope`, y debido a la [cadena prototipica](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) de un `$scope` padre y su `$scope` hijo, es el hijo el que posee la nueva propiedad, pero no es accesible desde el padre.

La forma de evitar este "problema" es usar un objeto **previamente declarado en el $scope padre**. Es decir que en el scope padre (MainController) defines un objeto y en el model interno del dialogo referencias una de las propiedades de ese objeto.

En MainController declaras un objeto, ejemplo:

```
$scope.datosDelModal = { newValue: "" };
```

y en el dialogo usas `datosDelModal.newValue` para bindear.

```
<textarea ng-show="tagEdit=='titulo'" ng-model="datosDelModal.newValue"
          placeholder="Title"></textarea>
```

Asi, cuando angular busca en la cadena de prototipos, encuentra el objeto `datosDelModal` en el padre y usa su propiedad interna para bindear el `ng-model`, por lo tanto no se crea newValue en el `$scope` hijo.

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias! tenía tiempo con ese problema